# the right way of react native matrix 2d?

Tags: css, matrix, react-native

I have a css3 tansform like

```
transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 5, 5);
```

so what's the react native "matrix array" is?

```
matrix1: [
1, 0, 0,
0, 1, 0,
5, 5, 1
]

matrix2: [
1, 0, 0,
1, 5, 5,
0, 0, 1
]

matrix3:[
1, 0, 5,
0, 1, 5,
0, 0, 1
]
```

all not right in the view....

Answer (score 1):

React Native uses 3D matrixes so your matrixes need to be 4x4. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Utilities/MatrixMath.js for details.

Answer (score 0):

React Native also offers a function to decompose your matrices into transformations: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Utilities/MatrixMath.js#L571

Be careful to have the same format of 4x4 row-major matrices